# Web Part displayed in another Web Part

Tags: web-part, newsfeed

I'm trying to build a "news feed" on my corporation's sharepoint site. I do not have access to the files that sharepoint creates, neither the original structure of the site. I am limited to using the web features when trying to design the site, and as such I have chosen using the "Welcome Page with Web Part Zones". That option has proven flexible enough to create a sensible layout.

But now I need to display a news feed. Is there a way to display the content of one Web Part Zone in another Web Part in another zone? For example so that each title in every new web part in that zone displays as a new news feed header?

Is there a better way to do this when not having access to anything but the web features?

Comment: There is something called WebPart Connectivity, which allows you to send data from one webpart to another, despiste their webpartzone location. This might be an option, of course depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way and its called an Interface, I have already answered someone yesterday with this question on connecting two or more webparts to share data.

[Connection between 2 web parts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43326/connection-between-2-web-parts/43331#43331)

just look for the post from me.

hope this helps!

Comment: Can this be done when the webparts I want to connect are on different webpartpages?

Comment: yes you can, I did it on the same page but different zones but you can do it on any page! http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/about-connecting-web-parts-HA001160885.aspx